# Cant login to multiple pages with VBA

Tags: vba, excel

can anyone assist with this script to see why my second IE session launches but the input data for password and user is not populating.

```
Sub MyLogin()
Dim Url As String
Dim ie As Object

    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .navigate "https://website"

        Do Until .readystate = 4
            DoEvents
        Loop

        .document.all.Item("username").Value = "userid"
        .document.all.Item("password").Value = "password//"
        .document.forms(0).submit

        Url = "https://website"
        Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
        ie.Visible = True
        ie.navigate Url
        ie = Nothing

        Do
        DoEvents
        Loop Until ie.readystate = 4

        .document.all.Item("Enter user name").Value = "userid"
        .document.all.Item("passwd").Value = "password"
        .document.forms(0).submit

    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't get a new object when you re-assign the reference inside a `With` block.  `With ie` increments the reference count for the *first* `ie` object you create, and everything that starts with a deference inside the block is referring to that one. So, when you do this...

> ```
> Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
> ```

...from ***inside*** the `With` block, the following lines of code...

> ```
>     .document.all.Item("Enter user name").Value = "userid"
>     .document.all.Item("passwd").Value = "password"
>     .document.forms(0).submit
> ```

...are all referencing the first `InternetExplorer.Application` object that you created (the one referenced by `With ie`).

This code demonstrates what is happening here (using a `Scripting.Dictionary` for illustration purposes):

```
Sub FooedUp()
    Dim foo As Scripting.Dictionary
    Set foo = New Scripting.Dictionary
    With foo                      'This now holds a reference to the 'foo' above.
        Debug.Print ObjPtr(foo)   'This is the pointer to that instance.
        .Add 1, 1                 'Add an item.
        Debug.Print .Count        'Count is now 1`.
        Set foo = New Scripting.Dictionary   'Re-use the 'foo' variable.
        Debug.Print ObjPtr(foo)   'The pointer is now different.
        Debug.Print .Count        '...but this is still bound to the first 'foo', prints 1.
    End With
End Sub
```

Hard to tell without the actual URL, but you're probably looking for something more like this (minus cleaning up after the first invocation):

```
Sub MyLogin()
    Dim Url As String
    Dim ie As Object

    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .navigate "https://website"
        Do Until .readystate = 4
            DoEvents
        Loop
        .document.all.Item("username").Value = "userid"
        .document.all.Item("password").Value = "password//"
        .document.forms(0).submit
    End With   '<--Un-bind the first IE object.

    Url = "https://website"
    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    ie.Visible = True
    ie.navigate Url
    With ie    '<--Bind the new IE object.
        Do
            DoEvents
        Loop Until ie.readystate = 4
        .document.all.Item("Enter user name").Value = "userid"
        .document.all.Item("passwd").Value = "password"
        .document.forms(0).submit
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: That solved it .Thanks for the break down makes sense.